# Number files based on modification time

Tags: files, rename, numbering

I have a set of files that I need to rename based on the creation time, by appending two digits to the beginning indicating the sequence.

Say, I have the following files:

```
Filename         Creation time
api.c            00:15
helloworld.h     00:05
ubuntu.iso       00:10
```

After renaming, the filenames should be of the form:

```
01_helloworld.h
02_ubuntu.iso
03_api.c
```

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you have the creation times stored anywhere, or should it be read from the file (if so, would the modify time do)?

Comment: What creation time? Unix doesn't have that by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pipes into less also `bash` assumed.

`ls -tr` prints files *oldest modified* first, others have commented on creation time.

```
a=0, ls -tr | while read line; do printf "%s \'%s\' \'%03d_%s\'\n" mv "$line" $((a=a + 1)) "$line"; done|less
```

Comment: ... and to actually have this working, do something like `a=0, ... ; done | bash` ?

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`:

```
( autoload zmv
set -- *(.Om)
pad=${#${#}}
zmv -n -Q '*(.Om)' '${(l:${pad}::0:)$((++i))}_$f' )
```

This gets the number of files first (to be able to calculate the length for zero padding via the `l` flag) then renames them using `zmv` with `-Q` to take advantage of the glob qualifiers `.Om` which select only regular files and sort them by their `mtime`.
Remove the `-n` (the *dry-run* switch) if you're happy with the result.